# Setting default variables for a PowerShell Invoke-Sqlcmd

Tags: sql, function, powershell

I have the function below called Invoke-SqlCmd:

```
function Invoke-Sqlcmd4
{
    param(
    [string]$ServerInstance = 'server.database.windows.net',
    [string]$Database = 'db',
    [string]$Uid = 'john',
    [string]$Pwd = 'pwd123',
    [string]$Query,
    [Int32]$QueryTimeout
    )

    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString="Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=False;User ID=john;Password=pwd123" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$Uid,$Pwd
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
    $ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
    [void]$da.fill($ds)
    $conn.Close()
    $ds.Tables[0]
}
```

which can be called by a line such as:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd4 -ServerInstance server.database.windows.net -Database db -Uid john -Pwd pwd123 -Query $query -QueryTimeout 60
```

However, I don't want to have to type out the connection string details every time I use this function. I.e. my parameters in the function are already set in the function so I don't want to have to re-type them every time.

I essentially want to be able to use a line of code like this:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd4 -Query $query -QueryTimeout 60
```

So it already knows from my function what my connection string is.
Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: What happens when you run it as it is? You've already provided defaults for those parameters so it should just accept them if you omit them from the function call

Comment: If I run `Invoke-Sqlcmd4 -Query $query -QueryTimeout 60` I get an error message `Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): Invalid object name 'table1'` where table1 is the name of the table I am querying on.

Comment: if `john:pwd123` are not your real credentials, you should probably replace them with placeholders `{2}` and `{3}` in the connection string

Comment: They are my real credentials. The server, database, user name and password are always the same so I want to set them as default within this function so that I can just write `Invoke-Sqlcmd4 -Query $query -QueryTimeout 60` for SQLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Invoke-Sqlcmd4
{
param(
[string]$ServerInstance = 'mysqlserver\mysqlinstance',
[string]$Database = 'master',
[string]$Uid = 'john',
[string]$Pwd = 'pwd123',
[string]$Query,
[Int32]$QueryTimeout
)

$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$conn.ConnectionString="Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=False;User ID=john;Password=pwd123" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$Uid,$Pwd
$conn.Open()
$cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
[void]$da.fill($ds)
$conn.Close()
$ds.Tables[0]
}

$myquery1='Select name from sys.databases'

Invoke-Sqlcmd4 -Query $myquery1 -QueryTimeout 60
```

Now I switched out your security and just used integrated in my case but it worked, you could easily switch it back.  I wasn't sure where you were passing in your Query but this should give you the idea.  You can make whatever $query variable you want outside of the function and pass it into your function.  Works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I can not use a windows login to connect to the SQL server I'm using, so I need the integrated security to be false and have a user name and password unfortunately.

Comment: so switch the security back to what you had, it should still work the same as I have it.  I just switched because I didn't need it.  Do you need to me to repost the code I have with your security piece added back?

Comment: I edited my answers code to include the connection security from your original example.  It should work.  Please let me know if you have any issues.